# Array displaying images, need to make another method that takes a paramter NUM to order how many pictures are shown

Tags: arrays, parameters

I explained that horridly in the title, and I apologize, am very new to java and don't quite understand some of it yet.

Anyway,

My cat animation runs to the middle of the screen, scratches twice, then continues to run to the end, is there anyway to write a method that will take an INT NUM and make the cat scratch x amount of times? Not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated

Here is my current code

```
/** Run the animation. */
public void nekoRun() {
    moveIn();
    scratch();
    //scratch2(5);
    moveOut();
}

/* Move Neko to the centre of the panel. */
private void moveIn() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getWidth()/2; i+=10) {
        xPos = i;
        // swap images
        if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
            currentImage = nekoPics[1];
        else 
            currentImage = nekoPics[0];
        repaint();
        pause(150);
    }   
}
    //neko stops and scratches in the middle of the panel twice
private void scratch() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {


        // Swap images.
        currentImageIndex = nextImageList[currentImageIndex];
        currentImage = nekoPics[currentImageIndex];


            repaint();
            pause(150);
        }
}
//Neko runs to the end of the panel
private void moveOut() {
    for (int i = xPos; i < getWidth(); i+=10) {
        xPos = i;
        // swap images
        if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
            currentImage = nekoPics[1];

        else 
            currentImage = nekoPics[0];
        repaint();
        pause(150);
    }   
}
```